# Can JMS be used in all cases where asynchronos messaging is required?

Tags: java, jms

I know that JMS is a option to handle asyn message communication between two discrete systems, my question is whether it has to be used in all cases or there is any specific scenario we can use our own implementation much like what JMS offers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS isn't exactly a simple API - it might be considered overkill for a small, simple app.

But when in doubt, it's generally better to go with the established standard and exisiting, time-tested implementation rather than falling victim to [NIH syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Invented_Here).

Answer (score 0):

You 're right but if the app is gonna be deployed in GAE then i may have to use some other API simlar to JMS.... any answer for this...